# Chrome app this plug-in only works on the desktop

Tags: java, plugins, google-chrome-app

I am not a developer, but I've been given the task of writing a chrome extension/google app.  The goal is to run chrome kiosk window to launch an internal HR page. I've used sample code and tested it as an extension in chrome. It does work. The login page comes up and I can log in. The issue is that the page requires the java plugin to run. Since it's kiosk mode you don't get the prompt to allow the plugin to run. What I get is the jigsaw icon in the middle of the page with the message "This plug-in only works on the desktop." Is there a way to allow plug-ins to run or for the plug-in to run?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It's a bug with the last update. Uninstall and re install again, it should fix it